# Inserting values from a dictionary as keys in another dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, and i would like to create a third where the values from number 1 becomes the keys in number 2 - i have searched alot but i think since my second dictionary is in a nested form i have not seemed to find an example. I am new to python, which maybe is why i have searched for the wrong things, and i hoped that posting here could help me solve it.

````
dict1 = {0: '123', 1: '456', 2:'789'}


dict 2 = 
{0: [{'id': 'abcd',
   'ocid': '134'},
  {'id': 'efgh',
   'ocid': '154'}],
1: {'id': 'rfgh',
   'ocid': '654'},
  {'id': 'kjil',
   'ocid': '874'}],
2: {'id': 'bgsj',
   'ocid': '840'},
  {'id': 'ebil',
   'ocid': '261'}]}

My desired output is: 

dict3 = 
{123: [{'id': 'abcd',
   'ocid': '134'},
  {'id': 'efgh',
   'ocid': '154'}],
456: {'id': 'rfgh',
   'ocid': '654'},
  {'id': 'kjil',
   'ocid': '874'}],
789: {'id': 'bgsj',
   'ocid': '840'},
  {'id': 'ebil',
   'ocid': '261'}]} ```
````

Comment: That's some invalid syntax with the `[0:` there

Comment: @Adam.Er8 you are right, i have corrected it, thanks!

Comment: Since dictionary entries aren't _necessarily_ in any defined order… how do you want to map values from one to specific positions in the other…? Or don't you care about the particular order?

Comment: `dict3 = {dict1[k]: v for k, v in dict2.items()}`…?

Comment: @deceze `int(dict1[k])` for an exact match to OPs expected output  :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as the two dictionaries are the same length and in the expected order to make the matches, you can iterate through the pairs of values in both dictionaries as follows:

```
keys = dict1.values()  # Get values from dict1
values = dict2.values()  # Get values from dict2

dict3 = {}  # Init new dict

# Iterate over tuples (dict1_value, dict2_value)
for key, value in zip(keys, values): 
   dict3[key] = value  # Use dict1_value as key and dict2_value as value
```

**EDIT**

Extending my original answer with @deceze suggestion for the case when key in both dictionaries can be used to perform the matches:

```
dict3 = {dict1[k]: v for k, v in dict2.items()}
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: thank you so much, it is precisely what i wanted! :)